# С++ Поиск в процессе значений, имея array of bytes

Tags: c++

Через Cheat Engine, выбрав тип array of bytes и введя (к примеру) 14 00 00 00 46, у меня в 99% случаях выходит 1 адресс в игре (к примеру 0xC83D38) И уже через этот адресс я могу получить например нужное мне значение. (получать значение по адресу я умею)
Как мне просканить этот массив в С++ в опреденном процессе и получить тот самый адресс?

Важно! Создать указатель через Cheat Engine в этой игре нельзя.
Читал похожую статью, но не понял где взять полный код https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488351/cant-find-an-array-of-bytes-match-from-another-process-memory

**Пожалуйста, перед отправкой кода из другого источника, проверьте работает ли он у вас.**

Comment: Шаг 1: найти в WinAPI функцию для чтения памяти другого процесса.

Comment: Прочитайте еще раз пост, вы меня не поняли. Я умею читать значения по адресу. Мне нужно осуществить поиск array of bytes в c++

Comment: Прочитал еще два раза, и не вижу, где вы написали, что уже умеете это делать.

Comment: Как мне сделать такой цикл, можно посмотреть ваш код?

Comment: Не знаю, у меня даже винда не стоит. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Думаю, следующей надо найти способ получить все валидные диапазоны адресов у процесса.

Comment: Выглядит интересно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2052418/2752075